# How do I show that the $n^{th}$ term of a sequence with constant $n^{th}$ differences is given by an $n$ degree polynomial?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In middleschool, I learned about arithmetic progressions where the first difference is constant and quadratic(?) progressions where the 2nd difference is constant. I want to prove that if the $n^{th}$ difference of a sequence is constant, then its $n^{th}$ term must be given by a $n$ degree polynomial.

Through a lot of algebra, I have proven that if the $n^{th}$ term of a sequence is given by a $n$ degree polynomial, then the first difference, $f(k+1)-f(k)$ , will be an $n-1$ degree polynomial due to all the $n$ degree terms cancelling out. Continuing this, the $n^{th}$ difference must be constant.

But I'm not sure if this is equivalent to proving that $f^{n}(k+1)-f^{n}(k)$ (where the subscript denotes the difference) implies the degree of the polynomial is $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You already showed: If $f(k)$ is a polynomial in $k$ of degeree $n$, then the $(n+1)^{\text{st}}$ difference is constant $0$.

Conversely, let $f$ be such that the $(n+1)^{\text{st}}$ difference is constant $0$. Let $g(x)$ be the unique $n$th degree polynomial such that $f(k)=g(k)$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n$. Then the $(n+1)^{\text{st}}$ difference of the sequence $f(k)-g(k)$ is constant $0$, as are the first few entries of previous differences (namely, by computing the repeated differences of the first $n+1$ values, you obtain a triangle of all $0$'s). If you work your way back up (now adding instead of subtracting), you will keep obtaining $0$'s. In other words, $f(k)=g(k)$ for all $k$.